# Fallo typeError: 'str' objeto is not callable en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy aprendiendo python y ando bastante atascado. Estoy haciendo un programa super simple y no me sale ni las primeras 60 líneas de código...

esto es lo que llevo:

```
class Animal():

    def __init__(self, nombre, raza, edad, pelaje, tamano):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.raza = raza
        self.edad = edad
        self.pelaje = pelaje
        self.tamano = tamano


    # COMPORTAMIENTOS ¿Qué es capaz de hacer nuestro objeto perro?
    def comiendo(self):
        if self.hambriento == True:
            print(self.nombre, "está comiendo")
        else:
            print("Parece que ", self.nombre, " no tiene hambre ahora.")

    def hambriento(self, hambriento):
        self.hambriento = hambriento
        if hambriento == "si":
            print(self.nombre, "tiene hambre")
        else:
            print(self.nombre, "Parece no tener hambre.")



perro = Animal("Boby", "Doberman", 0, "Marrón", "10cm")

test = 4
while test != 0:
    print("0 termina. 1 Perro con hambre. 2 Perro sin hambre. 3 dar de comer")
    test = int(input("Introduce un número: "))

    if test == 1:
        perro.hambriento("si")
    elif test == 2:
        perro.hambriento("no")
    else:
        print("Algo")
```

El fallo viene cuando selecciono un número por segunda vez, me suelta el error mostrado en el título, ¿en qué me estoy equivocando?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás definiendo el método hambriento con el mismo nombre que la variable self.hambriento. La primera vez que se ejecuta sobreescribes el método por un string, la segunda vez que se ejecuta, hambriento ya no es un método, sino un string que, efectivamente, no se puede llamar.

Comment: Buenas, no entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres. ¿Me podrías explicar un poco más? Algunos conceptos básicos me cuesta entenderlos. Perdona la torpeza.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Date cuenta de que tu clase `Animal` tiene un método llamado `hambriento` (`self.hambriento()`). Cuando ejecutas este método, dentro de él haces `self.hambriento = hambriento`. Tú piensas que estás guardando el valor en un atributo pero estás borrando el método (que tiene el mismo nombre) y lo estás convirtiendo en un string. Como estás llamando a este método en un bucle, la primera vez se ejecuta, se borra a sí mismo (transformándose en un string), y la segunda vez que intentas llamarlo ya no existe ese método.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!